# nginx под Windows: возврат статических файлов, как настроить nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

Мой nginx.conf:

```
location / {
            # root   'D:\company\name\layout-manager\frontend\public';
            # index  index.html;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3080;
        }

        location /json/ {
            root 'D:\company\name\layout-manager\json\';
        }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что если оставить только первый location, то процесс nginx запускается и по адресу localhost:80 открывается приложение, но если же добавить второй location для статических файлов, то процесс не запускается... Что я делаю не так?

Пробовал также вот так:

```
location ~ \.(json)$ {
            root 'D:\company\name\layout-manager\json\';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ \.(json)$ {
            root D:/company/name/layout-manager/json/;
        }
```

Такая конфигурация сработала (нужно было убрать кавычки)